# WooCommerce Stripe Plugin not showing up in settings

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

This is probably a simple thing but I have tried installing the WooCommerce Stripe Gateway plugin but it's not showing up in my WooCommerce settings under checkout.

My Installed plugins -

[image: Plugins]

And under WooCommerce > Settings > Checkout -

[image: Checkout Options]

I have tried installing it by searching for it under plugins and manually importing the downloaded zip file but neither seem to make any difference.

I've also have enabled SSL as I'd read that also might be the issue but still no joy.

Comment: It's most likely a plugin or theme conflict. Try changing the theme to a default WordPress theme and disabling plugins until you find the cause of the conflict.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be. I've just tried disabling every plugin apart from WooCommerce and Stripe Gateway and reverting to the default theme but still nothing!

Comment: Strange... It's working fine on my own website. You have everything updated, right? I can see you have the latest version of WooCommerce and WooCommerce Stripe Gateway but is WordPress up to date? I suppose you could set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in the `wp-config.php` file to see if that shows anything and also check your PHP error logs for any clues...?

Comment: Yeah everything is up to date. There is a post here https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/ive-activated-the-stripe-plugin-but-not-showing-up-as-an-option-in-woocommerce which looks looks identical but unfortunately there is no answer

Comment: Also, which version of PHP is your server running?

Comment: The server is CentOS 7 so the PHP version is 5.4. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes, Stripe for WooCommerce requires a minimum PHP version of 5.6.0 - I've just added this as an answer too. You really need to get that PHP version updated either way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe for WooCommerce requires a minimum PHP version of 5.6.0. If you are running a version prior to this then this will most likely be the cause of your problem.